# MigraDoc Formatting Top Align Paragraph with TextFrame

Tags: format, alignment, migradoc

Very new to this... I can't seem to get the Paragraph on the lower/left to top align with the rotated TextFrame on the right. Is there a way to do this in MigraDoc? (note: if it matters, the red text flows onto multiple pages)

Also, I would like the TextFrame to show up on each generated page, but it doesn't.

[image]
[image]

```
public static Document CreateWorkOrderPDF2(Document document, string filename, string WorkOrderHeader, string myMessage)
    {
        Section section = document.AddSection();
        section.PageSetup.PageFormat = PageFormat.Letter;

        section.PageSetup.StartingNumber = 1;

        section.PageSetup.LeftMargin = 40;
        //Sets the height of the top margin
        section.PageSetup.TopMargin = 100;
        section.PageSetup.RightMargin = 40;
        section.PageSetup.BottomMargin = 40;

        //HeaderFooter
        HeaderFooter header = section.Headers.Primary;
        header.Format.Font.Size = 16;
        header.Format.Font.Color = Colors.DarkBlue;

        MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Shapes.Image headerImage = header.AddImage("../../Fonts/castorgate.regular.png");
        headerImage.Width = "2cm";

        Paragraph headerParagraph = header.AddParagraph(WorkOrderHeader);
        headerParagraph.Format.Font.Name = "Consolas";

         //Vertical Text
        TextFrame myTextFrame = section.AddTextFrame();
        myTextFrame.Orientation = TextOrientation.Downward;
        //moves text to the right
        myTextFrame.Left = 550;
        myTextFrame.Width = 10;
        myTextFrame.Top = 0;
        myTextFrame.Height = 150;

        Paragraph myP = myTextFrame.AddParagraph();
        myP.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left;
        myP.Format.Font.Name = "Consolas";
        myP.Format.Font.Size = 8;
        myP.AddText(WorkOrderHeader);
        myP.Format.Borders.Width = .5;


        //BODY PARAGRAPH
        Paragraph bodyParagraph = section.AddParagraph(myMessage);
        bodyParagraph.Format.Font.Size = 10;
        bodyParagraph.Format.Font.Color = Colors.DarkRed;
        bodyParagraph.Format.Borders.Width = .5;
        bodyParagraph.Format.RightIndent = 50;

        Paragraph renderDate = section.AddParagraph();
        renderDate = section.AddParagraph("Work Order Generated: ");
        renderDate.AddDateField();

        return document;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all you have to add is `myTextFrame.WrapFormat.Style = WrapStyle.Through;`

Comment: Thanks! I wish I had asked two days ago!! :)